# NetBeans FileChooser. How do I use it to copy a file from one location to another defined in a string?

Tags: java, swing, file, file-io

I know how to perform simple operations with FileChooser within netbeans but when it comes to more complex ones, I'm getting a little stuck. So far I'm able to make use of a picture attained from the user's file system on the JFrame as below:
But I don't know how to use it to copy a file from one location to another defined in a string?

code:

```
private void ImageAtattchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int o = jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (o == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File f = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
        jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("" + f));
    }
```

Comment: The JFileChooser does just that, lets the user choose a File. Any actions on the File once chosen have nothing to do with the JFileChooser, but all to do with your code. You will want to go through a Java file tutorial, any file tutorial, which Google can help you find, and then read on the basics of Java file handling.

Answer (score 3):

> "But I don't know how to use it to copy a file from one location to another defined in a string?"

Assuming you trying to save an image file, just use `ImageIO.read` and `ImageIO.write`

1. Read the image you get from the file

   ```
    image = ImageIO.read(file);
   ```
2. Write it to a different file

   ```
   ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",new File("C:\\path\\to\\destination\\" 
                                                          + file.getName()));
   ```

---

See more  at [**ImageIO api**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html). Also see [**Basic I/O**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) for saving other formats, besides just images.

---

You can run this example, just change the file path.

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class SaveImageFile {

    public SaveImageFile() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Save Image");

        JButton saveImage = new JButton("Browse");
        saveImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "JPG, GIF, and PNG Images", "jpg", "gif", "png");
                chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println("You chose to open this file: "
                            + file.getName());
                    BufferedImage image;
                    try {
                        image = ImageIO.read(file);
                        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",new File("C:\\path\\to\\destination\\" + file.getName()));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(SaveImageFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }              
                }
            }
        });
        frame.add(saveImage);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SaveImageFile saveImageFile = new SaveImageFile();
            }
        });
    }
}
```